# Subtracting a timestamp from present-time in PHP, express in minutes

Tags: php

I have a variable `$minutes` that expresses a point in time like this: **2011-08-31 21:02:15**

How could I subtract it from the present time, and express the difference in minutes?

Comment: Does your timestamp comes from the database? You may want to do the calculation in SQL instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$minutes = (int)((time()-strtotime($minutes))/60);
```

[Example Here](http://codepad.org/ljIubx2i)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the DateTime and DateInterval classes.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime("2011-08-31 21:02:15");
$minutes = $now->diff($then)->i;
```

If you have a UNIX timestamp instead of a string, you can do this instead:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime();
$then->setTimestamp(myTimestamp);
$minutes = $now->diff($then)->i;
```